# Как привязать действие к элементу контекстного меню в PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside6

Вот кусочек кода тестового контекстного меню:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
    context = QMenu(self)
    context.addAction(QAction("test 1", self))
    context.addAction(QAction("test 2", self))
    context.addAction(QAction("test 3", self))
    context.exec(e.globalPos())


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()
```

Я не знаю, как, например, написать, чтобы при нажатии на элемент меню, в консоли выводилось его название. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

Вынести в переменную объект QAction

```
a = QAction("test1", self)
a.triggered.connect(lambda: print("test1"))
```

Ну примерно так, есть еще различные сигналы, кроме triggered

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Ну так я не знал, как привязать функцию, в этом  заключался вопрос